# How to change color of ToolbarItem with navigationBarLeading placement in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, toolbar

I need a title to be on the left side of a navigation bar. I use the following code:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Text("Title")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is displayed blue and as a button. Is it possible to change its color to black somehow? `foregroundColor`, `accentColor` do not work. Also, I tried to use a disabled button with `Text("Title")` inside. But it was displayed grey in that case. Not color, nor `PlainButtonStyle` were applied.

Answer (score 21):

By default if you add a single `Text` it's displayed as a `Button`.

Then, to change its color you need to set the `accentColor` of the NavigationView (as this button is displayed in the navigation bar):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Test")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text("Title")
                    }
                }
        }
        .accentColor(.black)
    }
}
```

If you don't want to change the `accentColor` in the whole NavigationView you can do:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        //...
    }
    .accentColor(.accentColor)
}
.accentColor(.black)
```

---

However, if you want this `Text` to behave like a `Text` and not like a `Button` you can use the following hack:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
    HStack {
        Text("Title")
        Text("")
    }
    .foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

Comment: this is an awesome solution - tried that, but didn't know it's only fixable by setting it to the NavigationView.But the text still automatically becomes a button. Only UIViewRepresentable keeps the Text as a Text

Comment: @Lonkly This is just how the toolbar works if you add just a Text (in the current version of SwiftUI). If you add two Texts wrapped in a HStack it behaves differently.

Comment: I am unable to get the VStack { // ... }.accentColor() to work to change the color of just one toolbar item. I am putting the VStack inside ToolbarItem(), around the Text(), like this: ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) { VStack { Text("hi") }.accentColor(.red). Is this what you meant or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Gary In the first solution it's the `.accentColor(.black)` on NavigationView which changes toolbar items color (not the `.accentColor(.accentColor)` on VStack). And it changes color for all toolbar items. If you want to change the specific item you need the 2nd solution (with `HStack`).

Comment: Ah, thanks. It works for individual items now. In fact it works with both VStack and HStack as long as I use .foregroundColor() and add an empty Text(""). Hopefully this hack of using an empty text won't break in the next update :)

Comment: is there a way to set the `accentColor` for all navigation views using UIAppearance ?

Answer (score 6):

Use an empty menu with custom style instead of changing accentColor.

```
    .toolbar {
         ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
             Menu(content: {
              
             }, label: {
                Text("Hello")
             })
             .menuStyle(RedMenuStyle())
         }
     }



struct RedMenuStyle : MenuStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Menu(configuration)
            .font(Font.system(size: 50))
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

---

Use navigationBarItems should you dispaly only text.

```
    .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Hello")
                                 .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                 .font(Font.system(size: 50)))
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked using `tint`:

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Button {

        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                .bold()
        }
    }
}
.tint(.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering, that `ToolbarItem` does not have any modifiers available, the only possible solution I see is using UIViewRepresentable that seems to ignore toolbars modifications:

```
.toolbar {
   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
      TitleRepresentation(title: "Test", titleColor: .red)
   }
}
```

...

```
struct TitleRepresentation: UIViewRepresentable {
    let title: String
    let titleColor: UIColor
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.tintColor = titleColor
        label.text = title
        return label
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {}

    typealias UIViewType = UILabel
}
```

Comment: This didnt work for me. Can you provide whole struct with toolbar?