# SwiftUI Xcode 12.3 can't change button size in toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Hi")
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.font(.largeTitle)` on `Image` has no effect, only if I use it inside a button.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like SwiftUI treats *single* toolbar items differently (applies their own style, size etc).

A possible workaround is to put a `Button` in a more complex view, as in: [How to change color of ToolbarItem with navigationBarLeading placement in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64468362/8697793)

Adapted to your example it can look like this:

```
ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
    HStack {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
        Text("")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the current version of SwiftUI and Xcode. Any ideas for alternatives?