# Accessibility of Image in Button in ToolbarItem

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voice-control

I am adding accessibility into my SwiftUI app, until I encountered a problem when adding an `accessibilityLabel(_:)` to a `Button` in a `ToolbarItem`. Here is some sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Content")
                .accessibilityElement()
                .accessibilityLabel("Content label") // This is here just to show Voice Control is working
                .navigationTitle("Test")
                .toolbar {
                    // Comment parts out below, depending on what you want to test
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        // What I want, but doesn't work:
                        // (Also tried adding the label to either the button
                        // label or the whole button itself, neither works.)
                        Button {
                            print("Pressed")
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .accessibilityElement()
                                .accessibilityLabel("Some label")
                        }
                        .accessibilityElement()
                        .accessibilityLabel("Some other label")
                        
                        // What I don't want, but does work:
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .accessibilityLabel("Another label")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing the accessibility with **Voice Control**. What is strange is that the accessibility label works for the image in the toolbar item, but not when inside a button in the toolbar item.

When I say the accessibility label doesn't work, it says `"Add"` instead of the expected label. I assume SwiftUI creates this label by default for the system image "plus", but I would like to change it.

The button accessibility labels also work when not in a toolbar item. Is this a bug, or some issue I have caused?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftUI treats single toolbar items differently (applies their own style, size etc). It looks like this applies to accessibility labels as well.

Fortunately, there is a workaround - see [SwiftUI Xcode 12.3 can't change button size in toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65675800/8697793).

In your case, the code should look like:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        HStack {
            Text("")
                .accessibilityHidden(true)
            
            Button {
                print("Pressed")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .accessibilityElement()
                    .accessibilityLabel("Some label")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(`accessibilityLabel` can be attached either to the `Image` or to the `Button`.)

Tested with Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3.

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't realise that the toolbar automatically applies styling to it, likely causing this issue. Thanks! Also I hid the text from accessibility so in VoiceOver it doesn't select the empty box.

Comment: Thanks, your hack works. (That's madness though)

Comment: When I tested this solution the resulting accessibility element did not have the button trait.  You might consider adding `.accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)` as well.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update: this has been fixed for iOS 15+.

My radar had 'Less than 10' similar reports, but is now actually fixed for iOS 15+. However, if you are supporting older versions, see the answer above by @pawello2222 and here is an updated version to only do the workaround if necessary:

```
/// Embeds the content in a view which removes some
/// default styling in toolbars, so accessibility works.
/// - Returns: Embedded content.
@ViewBuilder func embedToolbarContent() -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        self
    } else {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .accessibilityHidden(true)

            self
        }
    }
}
```